# Conditional probability - sampling light bulbs

Tags: probability

There is a box with 12 light bulbs inside and only 4 of them work. 3 light bulbs are sampled one after another. I'm asked to find the probability that every light bulb works.

Let $A_n$ be the event in which the nth light bulb works, then we need to find $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)$. I calculated the probability for each event and then multiplied them: $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) = \frac{4}{12}\frac{3}{11}\frac{2}{10} = \frac{1}{55}$. The correct answer uses conditional probability and the result is different, why? I don't understand it intuitively.

EDIT: I'll copy paste the solution here:

$P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) = P(A_3 | A_1 \cap A_2) P(A_2 | A_1) P(A_1) = \frac{6}{10}\frac{7}{11}\frac{8}{12} = \frac{14}{55}$

This solution seems to match the solution for the opposite problem (probability of the three light bulbs not working), so I think they made a mistake.

Comment: Firstly: are you sure that the correct answer is different? I think that $\frac1{55}$ is correct. Secondly: "I calculated the probability for each event and then multiplied them". No, you did not, because $P(A_1)=P(A_2)=P(A_3)=\frac4{12}$. E.g. the second factor in your calculation is not $P(A_2)$ but is $P(A_2\mid A_1^c)$ (as it should be).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me to think more clearly about what I'm doing.

Comment: It seems that $8$ bulbs work, since $P(A_1)=\frac8{12}$. (Or the question might have been: what is the probability that *none* of $3$ sampled bulbs works?)

Comment: I think they made a mistake in phrasing the question. Thanks!

Comment: There is a mistake in my first comment. I meant $P(A_2\mid A_1)$ instead of $P(A_2\mid A_1^c)$. Slip of the pen, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N =$ Total # light bulbs and $W =$ # working light bulbs at any point of time.

1. Before $A_1$ occurred: $N=12,\; W=8\; \Rightarrow P(A_1)=\frac{W}{N}=\frac{8}{12}$.
2. After $A_1$ occurred and before $A_2$ occurred: $N=11,\; W=7\; \Rightarrow P(A_2|A_1)=\frac{W}{N}=\frac{7}{11}$ (since one working blub was drawn, both $N$ and $W$ will decrease by $1$).
3. After $A_2$ occurred and before $A_3$ occurred: $N=10,\; W=6\; \Rightarrow P(A_3|A_1 \cap A_2)=\frac{W}{N}=\frac{6}{10}$ (since another working blub was drawn).

Combining, with chain rule, $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) = P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)P(A3|A1 \cap A_2)=\frac{8}{12}.\frac{7}{11}.\frac{6}{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

There are 12 light bulbs, eight of which work.  The probability the first bulb drawn works is 8/12= 2/3.  If you do draw a working light bulb the first time, that leaves 11 bulbs 7 of which work so the probability of drawing a working light bulb now is 7/11.  If you do draw a working light bulb on the second draw, that leaves 10 bulbs, 6 of which work so the probability of drawing a working light bulb on the third draw is 6/10= 3/5.  The probability of three working bulbs in three draws is (2/3)(7/11)(3/5)= 14/55.

Comment: I misread the problem.  I thought  "8 worked and 4 did not" rather than "4 worked and 8 did not".  What I calculated was the probability of getting 3 that did not work.  The correct answer is (4/12)(3/11)(2/10)= (1/3)(3/11)(1/5)= 1/55.

Comment: please update to get upvoted